# React: img onLoad and Chicken/Egg problem I cannot escape

Tags: reactjs

I have a React control that renders a bunch of images. My goal is to avoid the flickering that is caused by an unknown time it takes React to load the images (yes, I know about inline image loading, let's pretend it doesn't exist for a moment)

I have an initialized array in my class:

```
  this.loadedImages = [];
```

For this purpose I use `onLoad` in this manner:

```
render () {

        let items = this.props.images.map((value, index) => {

            let style = {};
            if (this.isImageLoaded(index))
                style = value.style;
            else
                style = {visibility: 'hidden'};

            return <img
                key={ index }
                onClick={ this.onClick }
                onLoad={ this.onLoad(index) }
                style={ style }
                src={ value.image }
                alt={ value.alt}/>
        });

        return (
            <div>
                 {items}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

my `onLoad` and `isImageLoaded` look like this:

```
onLoad = (index) => {

       if (!this.isImageLoaded(index)) {
           this.loadedImages.push(index);
       }
    };

isImageLoaded = (index) => {

        let isloaded = this.loadedImages.includes(index);
        if (isloaded)
            console.log(index + " is loaded!");
        else
            console.log(index + " is NOT loaded ");
        return isloaded;
    };
```

The issue is that once my page loads, the images switch from a "not loaded" into a "loaded" mode -- BUT there is only **ONE RENDER** that occurs before the images are loaded, thus the `{visibility: 'hidden'}` style remains permanent.

So my page loads without images. Now, if I **click** my component even once, the images will appear correctly because the component is forced to re-render (since now the images are loaded). BUT there is no option for me to force such a re-draw programmatically from the `onLoad` function as I'm getting a warning I should not be doing that from `render`...

My question is: how can I break the chicken/egg problems here and re-render my component once any image completes its loading.

Comment: It's not clear to me what type of flickering you're referring to: re-sizing based on content? I mean, there's always going to be a render before image requests finish processing--that's why there's various placeholder solutions. If you don't want to render before they're loaded then stop rendering something before they're loaded--an empty div might still take up space depending on your CSS.

Comment: I have an SVG which I project onto a yellow background div. The div displays empty, and only when the SVG loads, it updates it. and yes, I am already not rendering before it's loaded. The problem is I cannot ASK the component to render itself again Once I DO get a positive confirmation the images have all loaded. So it stays "empty" until I actually CLICK it, which makes it render itself again and shows the loaded images.

Comment: `onLoad` tells you that the image has been loaded, so you can set the visibility style then. If you set state, that will cause a re-render, so in the onLoad, you can set this index on the state as 'loaded', then when setting style in the render, check if 'loaded' is true or false and style accordingly.

Comment: I suggest the following: Store your array of images as state objects which have a 'loaded' flag (instead of a loaded images array). Then when you call your onload function you update that flag (updating state and causing your app to re-render). I believe that should solve the issue..

Comment: I don't call onLoad. The system does because put an `onLoad=......` prop inside my `render` function. Because of that, I cannot call `setState` from `onLoad`. If I do, the system does not re-render and issues a warning I should not be doing that. How do I break this cycle? How do I define my `onLoad=...` outside of the render JSX?

Comment: You should be able to call 'set_state' from js event handlers like onLoad so not sure what would cause that error.

Comment: I don't know what's causing it, but calling `setState` from my `onLoad` callback issues this: `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest combining your loadedImages data with the your other image state (as a boolean flag on each) and updating it using `setState` every time one loads (your headaches are due to this separation and the fact that you are having to manually keep them synchronised).

Then map over the single array of images (including loading state), using something like the src for the key.

Comment: I've done just that. Images are loaded in the state. the `onLoad` updates the state with the image being ready, which triggers a render. Being relatively new to React I needed to adhere to the concept. You work with states and props. Do not "change the world" f by other means and especially from the render function.

Comment: exactly! if it's too difficult and complicated, you've probably gone wrong :-)